# How to change values of every id in this nested object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested

I have data structure similar like this

```
{"id": 1, "a": [{"id": 2, "b": [{"id": 3, "c": [{"id": 4}]}]}]}
```

I would like to change every `id` to `null`.

I know I could do loops and manually assign `null` to `id`. Is there any easy way to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x),(k,v)=>k==='id'?null:v);` - of course, this doesn't mutate the original - but you didn't specify if you wanted to mutate in place or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without changing the object to a JSON string, you could use recursion:

```js
function clearIds(obj) {
    if ("id" in Object(obj)) obj.id = null;
    Object.values(Object(obj)).forEach(clearIds);
}

// Demo
let obj = {"id": 1, "a": [{"id": 2, "b": [{"id": 3, "c": [{"id": 4}]}]}]};
clearIds(obj);
console.log(obj);
```

This mutates the given object in place.

For fun: the same function as a one-liner:

```js
const clearIds = o => "id" in Object(o) && (o.id = null) || Object.values(Object(o)).forEach(clearIds);

// Demo
let obj = {"id": 1, "a": [{"id": 2, "b": [{"id": 3, "c": [{"id": 4}]}]}]};
clearIds(obj);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: oh, now that's not fair :p an in-place one-liner - I can't upvote you twice!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot @trincot, this is really definitely helpful. You are a life saver. What a solution by one liner!!

Answer (score 2):

Bravo's comment was illuminating so I hope they don't mind if I expand on it here.

1. Turn the object into a string.
2. Parse it back into an object again.

What I didn't know is that `JSON.parse` has [a "reviver" function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#using_the_reviver_parameter) that allows you to transform the string value as it's being parsed.

```js
const data = {"id": 1, "a": [{"id": 2, "b": [{"id": 3, "c": [{"id": 4}]}]}]};

// Turn the data into a string
const str = JSON.stringify(data);

// Parse the string back to an object
// but using the reviver function to turn the value of any id
// keys to null
const newObj = JSON.parse(str, (key, value) => key === 'id' ? null : value);

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: All good - I wasn't sure if OP wanted to change in place or not - change in place would be different - recursively dive into the object - but not that hard either. I just like one liners

Comment: Yeah, I just didn't know about the reviver function and thought it was fascinating.

Comment: useful for dates in WCF when you want to (need to) bypass loading microsofts cruft for using WCF - if that makes any sense - in JSON format, dates are "encoded" like "/Date(1234567890)/" - I also use the stringify `replacer` for sending dates to WCF

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andy, this is really definitely helpful. I have also just thought of converting it to string and use regex to replace id values with null. But your solution doesn't have to use regex. Good Job! And yea, the output is correct. It's what i want.